# How can I draw isomorphic graphs in TeX? like this picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw   isomorphic graphs in TeX? like this picture
[image]

Comment: Have a look at part IV of the TikZ documentation.

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
  Bullet/.style     = {fill=black,draw,color=black,circle,minimum
  size=3pt,scale=0.8},
}
\node[Bullet,label=left:{$u_1$}] (u1) at (0,2) {};
\node[Bullet,label=above:{$u_2$}] (u2) at (1,3){};
\node[Bullet,label=right:{$u_3$}] (u3) at (2,2){};
\node[Bullet,label=right:{$u_4$}] (u4) at (2,0){};
\node[Bullet,label=left:{$u_5$}] (u5) at (0,0){};
\draw[thick] (u1) -- (u2) -- (u3) -- (u4) -- (u5) -- (u1);
\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
  \node[Bullet,label=left:{$v_1$}] (v1) at (0,2) {};
  \node[Bullet,label=above:{$v_2$}] (v2) at (1,3){};
  \node[Bullet,label=right:{$v_3$}] (v3) at (2,2){};
  \node[Bullet,label=right:{$v_4$}] (v4) at (2,0){};
  \node[Bullet,label=left:{$v_5$}] (v5) at (0,0){};
  \draw[thick] (v1) -- (v3) -- (v5) -- (v2) -- (v4) -- (v1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @أحمدبوخاري If the solution worked for you please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) and perhaps [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).